# How do lists work in python recursion and why does int + list in recursion not fail?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm just starting out in learning recursion and after reading some articles I am wondering why it looks like recursion ignores operand errors. For example, I know you can't add an integer to a list and I know the following cannot execute:

```
>>> 1 + [2,3]
```

That will and should produce an unsupported operand type error.

However, when the following code is passed [1,2,3] it executes without fail:

```
def list_sum_recursive(input_list):
    # Base case
    if input_list == []:
        return 0

    # Recursive case
    else:
        head = input_list[0]
        smaller_list = input_list[1:]
        return head + list_sum_recursive(smaller_list)
```

The output is 6, which is correct for the sum of the elements in the list, but when I try to map out the stacks all I see is a stack of int + list which in my mind I know should throw an error. What am I not getting about how lists work in recursion? Can anyone explain to me why this code executes without throwing an error?

Comment: The *input* is a list, but the *output*, the value that you're summing over, is an integer. If you passed a list *of lists*, you'd see the same TypeError.

Comment: `return head + list_sum_recursive(smaller_list)` is the addition of an `int` + the *return* of a function taking a list. Which, btw, happens to be an `int` as well! Your base case is `return 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_sum_recursive` doesn't *return* a list; it returns the sum of the values in its argument:

```
list_sum_recursive([]) == 0

list_sum_rescursive([1]) == 1 + list_sum_recursive([])
                         == 1 + 0
                         == 1

list_sum_rescursive([1, 2]) == 1 + list_sum_recursive([2])
                            == 1 + (2 + list_sum_recursive([]))
                            == 1 + (2 + 0)
                            == 1 + 2
                            == 3
```

If you were to provide type hints for this function, it might look something like

```
def list_sum_recursive(input_list: List[int]) -> int
```

Not just any list can be passed, as it is assumed that `input_list[0]` will be something you can add to (ultimately) 0.

Comment: Thank you! This explained it.

Answer (score 2):

The line you're confused about must be `return head + list_sum_recursive(smaller_list)`. You're right, this would be problematic if head is an `int` and the other object returned by the recursive call is a list - however, ask yourself, at what point does your function ever return a list? Your function can either return 0 (the base case), or it can return head + some int.